# Regarding continuity and the value of the function at the point of discontinuity.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, continuity, boundary-value-problem

Suppose while solving a boundary value problem, we have a two piece solution $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ where $f_1(x)=f(x)$ for $x < x_0$ and $f_2(x) = f(x)$ for $x>x_0$. If there is a matching condition $f(x_0) = f_1(x_0) = f_2(x_0)$. 
Is that the same as saying that $f(x)$ must be continuous across $x = x_0$?

Comment: What does "across $x=x_0$" mean?  Does "across" mean "at?"  If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous in some neighborhood of $x_0$, then the matching implies that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: Right, I should probably explain why I used that term. I am looking at waves propagating on an interface or boundary separating fluids of disparate densities. Typically the conditions say "continuous across the interface" and it is in that same vein that I mean continuous across $x=x_0$. I think across does mean at in this context, does it not?

Comment: Yes, since the propagating waves are smooth functions, then they will be continuous in neighborhoods of $x_0$.  The enforcement of the BC $f_1(x_0)=f_2(x_0)$ simply makes $f$ continuous at $x_0$.  Suppose that you have a degree of freedom in choosing $f_1$ (i.e., $f_1(x)=Ag(x)$ for smooth $g$.).  Then, we find $A$ so that $Ag(x_0)=f_2(x_0)\implies A=f_2(x_0)/g(x_0)$ provided $g(x_0)\ne 0$.  Then, $f_1(x)=\frac{f_2(x_0)}{g(x_0)}g(x)$ will be continuous from the left at $x_0$ with $f_1(x_0) = f_2(x_0)$.  And thus, $f$ will be continuous from both the left and right, and thus continuous.